# Click a button or a link to set as a default option using <select> another page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So I would like a similar function however my issue is that I am trying to use this code on 2 pages so when a button or link pressed.  it will automatically set the `<option>` as the option that is selected on the other page.

https://jsfiddle.net/8RUBj/15/ (similar to this)

```js
$('.select-change').click(function() {
  $('#City').val($(this).data('val')).trigger('change');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>


<div data-role="page" id="page12">
  <div data-theme="e" data-role="header">
    <a href="#page1" data-icon="back" data-transition="flow" data-direction="reverse" data-ajax="false">Back</a>
    <h3>
      jQuery Mobile App
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <label for="City">Select City</label>
    <select name="City" id="City">
      <option value="">Select city...</option>
      <option value="A">Auckland</option>
      <option value="W">Wellington</option>
      <option value="C">Christchurch</option>
      <option value="Q">Queenstown</option>
      <option value="D">Dunedin</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <div data-role="controlgroup">
      <a data-role="button" data-val="A" class="select-change" id="btnAuckland">Auckland</a>
      <a data-role="button" data-val="W" class="select-change" id="btnWellington">Wellington</a>
      <a data-role="button" data-val="C" class="select-change" id="btnChristchurch">Christchurch</a>
      <a data-role="button" data-val="Q" class="select-change" id="btnQueenstown">Queenstown</a>
      <a data-role="button" data-val="D" class="select-change" id="btnDunedin">Dunedin</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Close Content Div of Page12 -->
</div>
<!-- Close Page12 -->
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOe0ysNsNCo (tried combining this, even though they are two different languages)

I have attempted to to combine another piece of code of how to pass variable from one page to another however no luck. Also I was wondering if jQuery would be the best code to use as I am only using CSS ,HTML, JavaScript and of course don't prefer any more issues adding another language?

Please advise

P.s I do apologise, I am a new coder and still getting my head around using stack-overflow. Otherwise I would have posted the code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor. Please do NOT try to BYPASS the restrictions like not entering code when posting JSFiddle links

Comment: We are not going to watch a youtube video to see what you mean